# Can't get TGT Ticket from the LSA Cache

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas

I have a java client which should receive a TGT ticket from LSA for client server authentication. So the krbc_{username} file  should not be used and is deleted. If i set the krbc_{username} with kinit.exe it works like expected but like said before not goal of my. But however the TGT in the LSA Cache can't be found. This is what i see in the console.

> > > Found no TGT's in LSA

A code fragement.

```
        try {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("Client", new    LibsCallbackHandler(userTicket));

        lc.login();
        Subject s = lc.getSubject();
        logger.info(s);
```

In the jaas.conf useTicketCache is set true. The Userticket is set if i log in with a dialog which i am using. If I use my username and password i receive a new ticket which is fine but not enough for single sign on. I also set 'allowtgtsessionkey' to 1 in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037715/kerberos-cached-ticket?rq=1) should contain the solution to your problem, let's quote the answer:

> Delete the krb5cc* file in a folder with the current user name under
> C:\Users

You need also to set a registry key, quoting:

> have also setup the following registry value to 1:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters
>
> Value Name: AllowTGTSessionKey
>
> Value Type: REG_DWORD
>
> Value: 1

Another problem can be related to ticket keyType, your application is going to ignore tickets that has an unsupported keyType.
For example, I had type-18 tickets into LSA that, without installing Java JCE extensions (from Oracle), doesn't work with Jaas.
In order to support a wider range of keyTypes, you need to install Oracle Java JCE extensions (adds support for AES >= 256..). The OpenJDK Java distribution supports all keyTypes/AES, no extensions needed.

You should also execute your application in a full kerberos debug mode, it will provide useful log messages:

```
java -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true -jar appname.jar
```